# Two functions not running OnClick?

Tags: javascript, html

When my button is clicked, I want two functions to run. The Choose button turns grew (which is working), however I also want the value of the sign up button at the bottom to change to 'sign up to gold'. However this isn't working, would be great if someone could help making these 2 functions run! :)

https://jsfiddle.net/u0n6v8zr/

```
<div class="homepagemembershippricingtable">
  <ul class="price">
    <li class="homemembershiptableheader">Platinum</li>
    <li class="homemembershiptableprice"><p class="membershippricetext">£10</p> / month</li>
    <li class="homemembershiptablecredits">3 credits, monthly</li>
    <li class="membershipchoosebutton"><button type="button" class="chooseemembershipbutton" onClick="setusermembershipchoice('Platinum');setmembershipayment()">Choose</button></td>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not very clear, you want to change the button text to "sign up to gold" whenever someone clicks on the choose platinum ?

Comment: No, if they choose platinum change to 'sign up to platinum'.. all the code is in the jsfiddle?

Comment: The JS fiddle has some errors that need to be fixed as well (not sure if this is what your actual code looks like).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `setmembershipayment` is not closed, so the browser doesn't run the function because it founds an error.

You forgot a close bracket. Update your function as the following example and it will work fine.

```
function setmembershipayment(){
    if (usermembershipchoice == "Silver") {
        alert("PAY FOR SILVER");
        document.getElementById("signupbutton").value = "SIGN UP TO SILVER";
    } else if (usermembershipchoice == "Gold") {
        document.getElementById("signupbutton").value = "SIGN UP TO GOLD";
        alert("PAY FOR GOLD");
    } else if (usermembershipchoice == "Platinum") {
        document.getElementById("signupbutton").value = "SIGN UP TO PLATINUM";
    } else { 
       alert("ERROR");
    } // THE MISSED BRACKED!! ;)
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks.. sorry for that stupid error!! but it is now running as I can see the alert("here") runs.. however I must have a problem with my if statements as the alerts for the 'usermembershipchoice ==' don't run & the value of the signup button doesn't change

Comment: Actually sorry the if statements are working as alert("Pay for Gold") does show, but why does the value of the signup button not change?

Comment: @Toby because you are setting "value". If you want to change the text shown, you have to use `document.getElementById("signupbutton").innerHTML = "SIGN UP TO PLATINUM";`

Comment: Ok thank you so much for your help!! Not sure why someone has downvoted your answer, I can't upvote though as I don't have enough rep